# How to prevent website access by server IP address on IIS server?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

Recently our application scanned and found that application should not be accessible from server IP address only should   Accessible through domain name
please tell me if anyone have make this work

Comment: Add a host name to your site binding.

Comment: You ever figure out how to block the IP address of the server from being served, specifically https.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your preferred approach is not necessarily more secure than the one you wish to prevent.  Just saying.

You can accomplish your objective by configuring the default site as blank site (or whatever permissions or response you want).

To do this, on your IIS,

1. Move your content to a different folder (like c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MySite)
2. Create a new site (IIS manager, right click "Sites". Add website")
3. Settings: "Physical path" points to your new content location (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite), "IP address" is unassigned,  "Host name" is the url for your site.
4. In IIS, right click "Default Web Site". "Edit Bindings".  For any of the entries with "IP address" of "*", Edit, and remove the host name.

This will force anyone going to your site with the IP, but not a correct hostname, to go to your default site, which will be empty.